# How to specify required properties on a requestBody object in an openApi project?

Tags: swagger, openapi

I have a yaml file for an openapi project that looks something like this...

```
components:

  schemas:

    Thing:
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: integer
        prop1:
          type: string
        prop2:
          type: string
        prop3:
          type: string

paths:

  /things:
      summary: Create a thing
      requestBody:
        description: Thing object
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/Thing'
        required: true

  /things/{id}:
    put:
      summary: Update a thing
      parameters:
      - name: id
        in: path
        description: Thing id
        schema:
          type: integer
      requestBody:
        description: Thing object
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/Thing'
        required: true
```

I am wondering:

Is there a way to configure this so that when creating a "thing" the list of required properties is different than when "updating" a thing?  (If I add the 'required' definition to components it affects all paths the same.)

For example, when creating a thing, prop1, prop2, and prop3 may all be required.  But when updating a thing, only prop1 may be required.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using specific objects for "update" and "create", which inherit from `Thing` and impose the restrictions you need:

```
Thing:
  type: object
  required:
    - id
  additionalProperties: false
  properties:
    id:
      type: integer
    prop1:
      type: string
    prop2:
      type: string
    prop3:
      type: string

ThingUpdate:
  allOf:
    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Thing'
  minProperties: 2

ThingCreate:
  allOf:
    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Thing'
  required:
    - prop1
    - prop2
    - prop3
```

You then obviously need to modify your `POST /things` endpoint to take a `ThingUpdate` in the request body rather than just a `Thing`, and likewise for `PUT /things/{id}` and `ThingCreate`.

To accomplish the "update" validation, notice that in the `Thing` base object I specified `additionalProperties: false` and in `ThingUpdate` I specified `minProperties: 2`; that enforces that there need to be at least 2 properties in the "Thing", with no properties other than `id`, `prop1`, `prop2` and `prop3` (I assumed `id` is required, so I put it at the top of `Thing`).

For the "create" validation, I simply inherited from the `Thing` base class and specified that all of the non-`id` properties are required.

---

There's some redundancy here with the `id` parameter, since it's not needed for "create", and for "update" it's specified in the path rather than in the request body. You could remove `id` from the `Thing` base object and modify `minProperties` in `ThingUpdate` to instead be `1`. Then, assuming you intend to add a separate `GET /things` endpoint where you want to retrieve all `Thing`s from your database or wherever, you can create a separate derived object `ThingGet` that includes `allOf:` `Thing` and adds the additional `id` property (under a `properties:` object).